# Saving a < /dev/null result from remote host to local machine in text file

Tags: bash, scripting

I have the following code, which retrieves data from a remote host and display on local machine display.

```
if [ $(nc -z 192.168.80.180 22; echo $?) -eq 0 ]; then
ssh root@$192.168.80.180 'df -h; free -m' < /dev/null
echo /dev/null | cat - $var.txt
fi
```

How can I capture the result and save to a file, I tried echo but it didn't work.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
< /dev/null
```

Binds the process standard output with `/dev/null` file.

> Saving a < /dev/null result ...

`/dev/null` is a file and does not produce a result.

> ```
> ssh root@$192.168.80.180 'df -h; free -m' < /dev/null
> ```

Runs `ssh` command with specified parameters and binds it's standard input with `/dev/null`.

`/dev/null` is a magic file. It always has size equal to zero. You can write anything to it. It's size still will be zero. You can't read anything from it. Cause it's size is always zero. Expression `< /dev/zero` is used to "close" a commands standard input.

For saving a process output it produces on standard output you can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution):

```
var=$(ssh root@$192.168.80.180 'df -h; free -m' < /dev/null)
```

or you can save the standard output of a process by binding it with a file:

```
ssh root@$192.168.80.180 'df -h; free -m' < /dev/null > result.txt
```

You can read more about bash [redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).

The line

> ```
> if [ $(nc -z 192.168.80.180 22; echo $?) -eq 0 ]; then
> ```

is just strange. Just:

```
if nc -z 192.168.80.180 22; then
```

The `if` expression is true if the command returns zero status. Comparing commands return status with zero `[ $(command; echo $?) -eq 0 ]` is just strange.

More about [if](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs).

Also always quote any expansions (unless you know you don't have to). So quote command substitution `[ "$(nc -z ...; echo $?)" -eq 0 ]`.